# Apache: Proxy websocket wss to ws

Tags: apache, websocket, wss

Does anyone know how can i proxy wss connection to ws?

For example:

> ProxyPass "wss://*"  "ws://*"

Comment: searching for the solution. Please share if you found a way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is to use rewrite rules:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
 RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://localhost:9001/api/$1 [P,L]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
 RewriteRule /(.*)           http://localhost:9001/api/$1 [P,L]
```

Comment: I have no idea why did I have to do this, but it really did work. I'm using a digitalocean ubuntu 16.04 LAMP stack droplet, and uploaded an example from the Ratchet php tutorial and it simply did not work until I added this part into my virtualhost definition, after literally trying everything for 12 hours straight. Thank you!

Comment: Doesnt work for me. I have my node websocket(ws) running over 5000. I want to route ws requests to wss