# Apache Config: Websockets Proxy WSS request to WS backend

Tags: apache, websocket, rabbitmq, stomp

Thanks in advance for any help.

I am attempting to use Apache as a proxy between the web browser using WSS and a backend WS server process.

Browser <---WSS---> Apache <---WS---> RabbitMQ Stomp

I have HTTPS properly set up in Apache and serving up pages via 443.

In the Apache site config:  .../sites-enabled/site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =MYSERVER.com [OR]
    RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.MYSERVER.com
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLProxyEngine On

    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYSERVER.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/MYSERVER.com/privkey.pem

    Redirect /wss /wss/
    ProxyPass /wss/ ws://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp/websocket/
    ProxyPassReverse /ws/ wss://127.0.0.1:15674/stomp/websocket/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    ServerName MYSERVER.com
    ServerAlias www.MYSERVER.com

</VirtualHost>
```

Javascript in browser:

```
<script>
  var ws = new WebSocket('wss://MYSERVER.com:443/wss');
  var client = Stomp.over(ws);
```

In the Chrome debugger I see:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://MYSERVER.com/wss' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 302

This is working great using just ws pointed directly at the backend, but I need to get wss working.

I tried to get a similar solution to this example, but was unable:
[Apache: Proxy websocket wss to ws](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211828/apache-proxy-websocket-wss-to-ws)

Answer (score 3):

This line `Redirect /wss /wss/` adds a trailing slash to `/wss` if not present (by default, it's a 302 redirect). And you're trying to connect to `wss://MYSERVER.com:443/wss`, which explains the redirect.

**Solution**:
try connecting to `wss://MYSERVER.com:443/wss/` (with the trailing slash). This should now work as expected.